# Confused about unit tests and what to actually test in my Xamarin Forms MVVM project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin.forms, mvvm, mvvmcross

So I've recently just started to add Unit Tests to an enterprise app that I'm developing myself. I found my self in a situation where I'm not sure what I should be testing and / or mocking.

I've read many articles and blogs and as far as I understand it, tests should be created from the users point of view and to only test what is observable and not the method implementation, basically treating the methods under test as a black box.

**Case 1:**
*Testing a Command which is an `MvxAsyncCommand` from the MVVMCross framework.*

From the users POV the only observable thing that happens is either the login fails with a message or they are logged in. I can test for the failure by mocking the Dialog Service but without knowing the internal of the method there is no way to test for a valid login.

So basically this test would be useless. Do I just forget it ?

**Case 2:**
*Testing methods with Xamarin Essential dependencies*

As with most Xamarin Forms projects most developers have a heavy dependency on Xamarin.Essentials. This causes a pain as any tested method which calls any of the essential methods will throw an exception as its not initialised and can't be as its device specific. I've found a community project which automates Interface generation for the concrete classes but this means I would be mocking methods I'm not supposed to know about.

This example highlights both cases.

```
public MvxAsyncCommand SignInCommand => new MvxAsyncCommand(async () =>
{
    IsLoginEnabled = false;

    var result = await UserService.SignInAsync(Username, Password);
    if (result != null)
    {
        Preferences.Set("username", Username);
        await NavigationService.Close(this, result);
    }

    IsLoginEnabled = true;

}, () => IsLoginEnabled);
```

So testing this command would always fail and never login as `UserService.SignInAsync` isn't mocked, there is only ever one outcome.

Even if I mocked `UserService.SignInAsync` (which I understand shouldn't be done as its 'black box') it would throw an exception when executing `Preferences.Set("username", Username)` which again could be mocked but it seems this rabbit hole would just get deeper.

Could anyone throw some light on what should or could be done here please ?

Comment: Did you get any solution for exceptions when executing Preferences.Set("username", Username)